# Using Dynamically Allocated Arrays in a Class Storage structure

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I am in my first year of C++ in university and my professor has assigned some review for our final test coming up in a month. I have done all the other questions, to my knowledge, correctly, yet these two questions are a bit strange. Essentially, my professor has created a class called `ListA` which uses a dynamically allocated array as the underlying storage structure. Given the code below, he wants us to do two things:

> - Write out the necessary private variables
> - Write the constructor for class `ListA`

For the constructor I wrote:

```
    List::List(int size)
    {
        array = new ItemType[size];
        length = 0;
        head = array[0];
    }
```

For the necessary private variables I wrote:

```
    itemType* array;
    int length; //to keep track how many elements are filled
    itemType* head; //to create pointer for first element in array
    itemType size;
```

I'm just not sure if these lines are correct. I feel like I'm close, but I need some help. Here is the .h file:

```
typedef int itemType;
class ListA
{
public:
List(int size);
~List();
/*
pre: an instance of lists exists
post: true if list is empty, false otherwise
*/
bool IsEmpty();
/*
pre: an instance of list exists
post: returns len
gth of the list
*/
int GetLength();
/*
pre: an instance of list exists
post: newItem is at the head of the list
*/
void PutItemH(itemType newItem);
/*
pre: an instance of list exists and is not empty
post: Returns the contents of the head of the list.
*/
itemType GetItemH();
/*
pre: an instance of list exists and is not empty
post: head of the list is deleted
*/
void DeleteItemH();
/*
pre: an instance of list exists an
d is not empty
post: contents of list nodes are displayed on subsequent lines  from head to tail
*/
void Print();
/*
Pre: an instance of list exists
Post: returns true if the target is in the list, false otherwise
/*
bool Find(itemType
target)
/*
Pre: an instance of list exists
Post: if a node contains target, the node is deleted and true is returned, else false is returned.
/*bool DeleteItem (itemType target)
private:
#notice that there are no member variables
.  See problem 14.
};
```

Comment: so, what exactly is your problem? what does not work? btw, your `head` seems superfluous as `array` is already pointing to the head, unless you are doing something like circular queue

Comment: In general, calling something a list doesn't make it a list. A datatype is effectively defined by its behavior, the semantics of its methods. A container where you can add and remove elements only at one point is usually called a _stack_. In your example, only the commented-out `DeleteItem` method differs from the methods of a stack container.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many member variables.

```
itemType* array;
int length; //to keep track how many elements are filled
itemType* head; //to create pointer for first element in array - Why ?
itemType size;
```

You can trim it down to the following

```
itemType* array;
int length;
int size;
```

The constructor should look like this:

```
List::List(int size):size(size), length(0)
{
    array = new ItemType[size];
}
```

This should be enough to satisfy the needs of all member functions.E.g:

```
bool ListA::IsEmpty() {return length == 0;}
int ListA::GetLength() {return length;}
```

`length` will increment when you add items to your underlying array.

Comment: Wrong - you do need a head if the list methods allow the head to change. (pust_front/pop_front methods come to mind). In fact, as the list nodes are independently deallocated, it's insufficent to know how may are in use, you need to know exactly which nodes are.